# Unity: add InputTracking to my script

Tags: unity, c#

I'm new to unity and 3D world developement so I'm following Unity's tutorial for beginners right [here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/getting-started-vr-development). And I'm in the section with title "Camera Nodes" where they gave me a c# script to attach it to the camera object.
I did attach it to the camera but the problem with the script when I debug it I get an error of undefined class:

```
The name 'InputTracking' does not exist in this context
```

And this is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpdateEyeAnchors : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject[] eyes = new GameObject[2];
    string[] eyeAnchorNames = { "LeftEyeAnchor", "RightEyeAnchor" };  

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            // If the eye anchor is no longer a child of us, don't use it
            if (eyes[i] != null && eyes[i].transform.parent != transform)
            {
                eyes[i] = null;
            }

            // If we don't have an eye anchor, try to find one or create one
            if (eyes[i] == null)
            {
                Transform t = transform.Find(eyeAnchorNames[i]);
                if (t)
                    eyes[i] = t.gameObject;

                if (eyes[i] == null)
                {
                    eyes[i] = new GameObject(eyeAnchorNames[i]);
                    eyes[i].transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                }
            }

            // Update the eye transform
            eyes[i].transform.localPosition = InputTracking.GetLocalPosition((VRNode)i);//--the error is this line
            eyes[i].transform.localRotation = InputTracking.GetLocalRotation((VRNode)i);//--and this one
        }
    }
}
```

This is the [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.InputTracking.html) of the class `InputTracking` in Unity's API, but I don't know how to add it to my script :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you add `using UnityEngine.VR;` to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `using UnityEngine.VR;` to the top of your file. `InputTracking` is located in that namespace, which is indicated by the docs.